# Principles of protection

Tags: security, operating-system

I am reading a chapter Sytem Protection of operating system of Peter Baer Galvin.

Inside the chapter there is a paragraph inside a subtopic Principles of Protection which I m not able to understand .

> An operating system following the principles of least privilege
>   implements its features,  programs ,system calls, and data structures
>   so that failure or compromise of a component does the minimum damage
>   and allows the minimum damage to be done. The overflow of a buffer in
>   a system daemon might cause the daemon to fail, for example ,but
>   should not allow the execution of code from the process's stack that
>   would enable a remote user to gain maximum privileges and access to
>   the entire system (as happens too often today).

Please help me to understand this pragraph.

Comment: While I generally hate Wikipedia CS articles, this one is a lot better than what you have. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the developers of a hardened (inherently relatively secure) OS should follow common sense and give a non-kernel process the absolute minimal amount of access it needs to do its job. If you don't do this, then anything executing at kernel privilege level can potentially crash the system or, worse, compromise it and wreak havoc on the system's data.